# How to run a windows batch file with node js

Tags: node.js, windows, batch-file

What I have tried: Using Node JS Child Process API to spawn the bat file in my projectfolder. But I couldnt get it running.

```
 projectfolder/
 ├──src/                       
 |   ├──app                 
 |        ├──home  
 |             ├──home.component.ts 
 |── my.bat (File Type: Bat shortcut)
```

**home.component.ts**

```
    let spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
      ls = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'my.bat']);

    ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log('stdout: ' + data);
    });

    ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log('stderr: ' + data);
    });

    ls.on('exit', function (code) {
      console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
    });
```

**Error**

> stderr: 'my.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> home.component.ts?71c4:159 child process exited with code 1

I have also tried

```
const exec = require('child_process').execFile;
    exec('my.bat', function (err, data) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(data);
    });
```

with error

> Error: spawn my.bat ENOENT
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:1050)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193)
>       at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I found the issue.

My File Type is a `Bat shortcut`

The above code only works for `Windows Batch File`, but not a `shortcut`